# Razor Dynamic SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, razor

I have the following C# code.

```
var var_db = Database.Open("Intranet") ;
var var_selectCommand = "SELECT Ticket_ID AS [Ticket], Logged_Date AS [Created], Ticket_Type AS [Ticket Type], Department, Priority, Forename, Surname, Ticket_Status AS [Status], Completed_Date AS [Completed], User_Assigned AS [User], Ticket_Subject AS [Subject] FROM Ticket_Data WHERE Ticket_Status = 'Open' ORDER BY Logged_Date DESC";
var var_searchTerm = "";

if(!Request.QueryString["Priority"].IsEmpty() ) {
    var_selectCommand = "SELECT Ticket_ID AS [Ticket], Logged_Date AS [Created], Ticket_Type AS [Ticket Type], Department, Priority, Forename, Surname, Ticket_Status AS [Status], Completed_Date AS [Completed], User_Assigned AS [User], Ticket_Subject AS [Subject] FROM Ticket_Data WHERE Priority = @0 ORDER BY Logged_Date DESC";
    var_searchTerm = Request.QueryString["Priority"];
}

if(!Request.QueryString["Department"].IsEmpty() ) {
    var_selectCommand = "SELECT Ticket_ID AS [Ticket], Logged_Date AS [Created], Ticket_Type AS [Ticket Type], Department, Priority, Forename, Surname, Ticket_Status AS [Status], Completed_Date AS [Completed], User_Assigned AS [User], Ticket_Subject AS [Subject] FROM Ticket_Data WHERE Department = @0 ORDER BY Logged_Date DESC";
    var_searchTerm = Request.QueryString["Department"];
}
```

I have the following markup.

```
            <select class="field" id="priority" name="Priority" >
                <option value="">Please choose...</option>
                <option value="Low">Low</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="High">High</option>
            </select>

            <select class="field" id="department" name="Department" >
                <option value="">Please choose...</option>
                <option value="Department 1">Department 1</option>
                <option value="Department 2">Department 2</option>
                <option value="Department 3">Department 3</option>
                <option value="Department 4">Department 4</option>
                <option value="Department 5">Department 5</option>
                <option value="Department 6">Department 6</option>
            </select>
```

If I want to search by 'Priority' or 'Department' only then this works, but what I would like to do is apply more than one search criteria and have it dynamically change the SQL query so I can bring back results only of a specific priority and from a specific department.

Can anyone tell me the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: We need the function headers and your submit mechanism. Is this in a controller or what? Your code looks fine. I suspect your parameters aren't being sent or aren't being received by the controller, or you're binding to a click event in the code-behind, and you don't have access to the values for some reason. I assume somewhere you're actually including your parameters into the SQL string? What you posted doesn't do that.

Comment: Oh... AND... If your second IF condition is true, it blows away the parameter you set in the first one. Use one variable for each thing - don't over-write them!

Comment: My impression reading your code is that your error is to use Request.QueryString instead of Request.Form (or quite simply Request). If you are reading the values from two dropdowns in a form, Request.QueryString is always empty and your conditions are never fulfilled.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit: you fundamentally changed your question, making the existing answer obsolete. If you have a new question or a follow-up question then you need to ask a new question (if there isn't already an existing answer to your question). Also keep in mind that Stackoverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, Apologies as I did not see your comment and wondered why my update had not taken effect so resubmitted it.  Please feel free to roll it back once more and I will search for this answer and if no answer is found I will ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some string concatenation to build up the query.  This should get you started.

```
var selectStatement = "SELECT Ticket_ID AS [Ticket], Logged_Date AS [Created], Ticket_Type AS [Ticket Type], Department, Priority, Forename, Surname, Ticket_Status AS [Status], Completed_Date AS [Completed], User_Assigned AS [User], Ticket_Subject AS [Subject] FROM Ticket_Data ";
List<string> whereConditions = new List<string>();

if(!Request.QueryString["Priority"].IsEmpty() ) {
    whereConditions.Add(" Priority = yourPriorityParameterHere ");
    //.....
}

if(!Request.QueryString["Department"].IsEmpty() ) {
    whereConditions.Add(" Department = yourDepartmentParameterHere ");
    //.....
}
var commandText = selectClause + " WHERE "+ string.Join(" AND ", whereConditions) + " ORDER BY LoggedDate DESC";
//......
//Fill in parameters, execute sql, live happy
```

Comment: A good suggestion, but this code will error in the database if both priority and department are empty.

Comment: @JeremyCook Like I said in my answer, this is only a starting point.  It isn't meant to be a copy/paste production ready piece of code.

Comment: OK, just making you and anyone that will use it aware. It's a pretty simple fix to address the issue I'm thinking of: `selectClause + (whereConditions.Any() ? " WHERE "+ string.Join(" AND ", whereConditions) : "")`.